# Java JDBC Return wrong generated keys

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to get an ID of a newly inserted row from my database.
After debugging and following the code step by step but it always returns a "0" value.

```
HashMap<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Integer generatedId = 0;
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
        rs.next();
        if (rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
            generatedId = rs.getInt(1);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        response.put("STATUS", "ERROR");
    }
```

The code sits in a static method called update which accepts a string with SQL query String.

```
public static HashMap<String, String> update(String query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes no sense.

If you call `rs.next()`, as you should, `rs.isBeforeFirst()` cannot possibly be true, and the following `rs.getInt()` would fail if it was.

Remove the test. It should really be `if (rs.next())` etc.